# Native AOT COM Indirect call guard check detected invalid control transfer

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, native-aot

I am trying to implement an COM functionality with C# and Native AOT and getting the following exception in target process "Explorer" "Indirect call guard check detected invalid control transfer." after passing my .NET Wrapped object.

This is Factory method that produces the wrapped COM object

```
 [UnmanagedCallersOnly]
 public static unsafe int CreateInstance(IntPtr self, IntPtr outer, Guid* guid, IntPtr* instance)
 {
     *instance = IntPtr.Zero;

     ComWrappers cw = new StrategyBasedComWrappers();
     XamlTap xamlTap = new XamlTap();
     *instance = cw.GetOrCreateComInterfaceForObject(xamlTap, CreateComInterfaceFlags.None);
     return HResult.S_OK;
 }
```

Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling Windows Defender's "Control Flow Guard" feature to see if that makes the problem disappear.  If that works, adding a [new issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues) could be a good way to arrive at a better solution.